# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^4}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Happened upon this in the quantum mechanics course while normalizing the momentum-space wave function. Thanks!

Comment: You may show through [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the substitution $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=u$ that
$$ \forall r>\frac{1}{2},\qquad I(r)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^r} = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(r\right)} \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(1+x^2)^4} = I(3)-I(4) = \left(1-\frac{5}{6}\right) I(3) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{32}}.\tag{2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: substitute

> $$x=\tan { \theta  } $$

Comment: Yes. I totally forgot about this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{(1+x^2)^4}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{(1+x^2)^3}-\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{(1+x^2)^4}$$
Now the indefinite integral $\;\displaystyle I_n=\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{(1+x^2)^n} $ is a standard integral which is  calculated recursively. Integration by parts yields the recurrence relation:
$$I_{n+1}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_n+\frac{x}{2n(1+x^2)^n}$$
whence the relations
$$J_{n+1}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}J_n,\quad\text{where}\enspace J_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{(1+x^2)^n},\qquad J_1=\frac\pi2.$$
We seek  $$J_3-J_4=\frac16J_3=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac 34J_2=\frac18\cdot\frac12J_1 =\frac{\pi}{32}.$$

Comment: He asked about the integral $\int \tfrac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^4}dx$, not $\int \tfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^4}dx$. It is a nice solution though.

Comment: @Brazilian: I had misread. But it's still simpler, I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: nice solution, I wonder why such solution  is not upvoted +1